# Comparing Values in a file with an array

Tags: java, arrays, file, tokenize

I have a .txt file with integers on each line e.g.

```
1
4
5
6
```

I want to count the occurrences of the values that are in an array with the file.

My code extract is this

```
String s = null;
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
while ((s = br.readLine()) !=null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (st.nextToken().equals(array[i])) {
                count++;
            }
```

Error Messages are

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
```

The file is in the same directory.

Could someone please give me a hand?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're trying to pull a new token for every iteration of the `for` loop - instead, you need to assign the result of st.nextToken() to a variable before the for loop, and then use that variable in the `if` statement.

```
String s = null;
String token = null;
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
while ((s = br.readLine()) !=null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        token = st.nextToken();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (token.equals(array[i])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```